# Android SherlockFragmentActivity call SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Originally, I have 2 Activities. A call B activities. Now I changed the A class extends SherlockFragmentActivity and B class extends SherlockFragment.

I tried to changed these in A class:

```
   private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

          if (tab.getPosition()==1) {
              B frag = new B();
              ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);

          }

      }

      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      @Override
      public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }


    }
```

//=============================

In B class:

```
public class Br extends SherlockFragment{


    /* Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.promotionslist_tableview);



        //get our listview
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView_promotionslist_table);
```

//==============================

BUT ERROR. 
1. onCreate
2. findViewById..

What i am wrong ?

please give me some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can now display the B fragement but the listview overlap on the main listview..?
Why ?

```
public class B extends SherlockFragment{

    View view; 

    /* Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.promotionslist_tableview);





        //get our listview
        ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView_promotionslist_table);
.
.
.
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.promotionslist_tableview, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Hi,I fixed. Build a base activity which extend SherlockFragmentActivity and the others are extend SherlockFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `onCreateView()` method in fragments:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);

        return view;
    }
```

There you can inflate a View and call findViewById like this:

```
view.findViewById(...);
```

Comment: public class B extends SherlockFragment{

    View view; 

    /* Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.promotionslist_tableview);
        
     



     //get our listview
  ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView_promotionslist_table);